# Custom Element Preset => Form Field: Images

Tags: typo3

I tried to create a typo3 template with a special div-tag. 
The editors should have the possibility to add images to the page-element. The goal should be the following code:

```
<div id="special_div_tag_in_template">
    <img src="first_image_from_editor_in_page_element.png" />
    <img src="second_image_from_editor_in_page_element.png" />
    <img src="third_image_from_editor_in_page_element.png" />
</div>
```

Is there a possibility to create a custom element preset / form field?

I hope some one has a hint how to solve with this problem. 
Thanks, Andreas

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `media` field of the page properties:

```
lib.headerImage = COA
lib.headerImage {
    wrap = <div id="special_div_tag_in_template">|</div>
    10 = IMAGE
    10 {
        file {
            import = uploads/media/
            import {
                field = media
                listNum = 0
            }
            // set the dimensions if you want
            height = 200
            width = 100m
        }
    }

    // create a copy and select 2nd image
    20 < .10
    20.file.import.listNum = 1

    // create a copy and select 3rd image
    30 < .10
    30.file.import.listNum = 2
}
```

Take a look at the [TYPO3 Wiki](http://wiki.typo3.org/TypoScript_Header_Image) for more examples of header images.

A different approach would be to create DS/TO in `TemplaVoila` and insert this as a flexible content element (FCE)